# How to change the container log location in a Dataproc cluster?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, google-cloud-dataproc

What is the correct way to change the container log location in a Dataproc cluster during cluster creation?

The default path is `/var/log/hadoop-yarn/userlogs` and I want to change it to a local SSD mount such as `/mnt/1/hadoop/yarn/userlogs`. I tried adding

> `--properties=yarn:yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs`

to the `gcloud dataproc clusters create` command but got the error -

> `bash: --properties=yarn:yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs=/mnt/1/hadoop/yarn: No such file or directory`

This is most likely because the local SSD gets mounted after the cluster is created. Can someone please help?

Comment: We have tentatively implemented a solution using an initialisation script but I'm not sure if that's the most efficient way to do it.

Comment: Hi @Jerry, For your requirement, you can try using a [Log Router](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/routing/overview#log-router) using which you can route the logs to Cloud Pub/Sub and using a subscriber client, you can pull the logs and store it into a local SSD. Let me know if that is helpful.

Comment: Hi Shipra - In our case, the end goal is not to store in a Local SSD. Rather we just want Yarn to use the Local SSD instead of the boot disk to store the logs while the job is run. Once done, the logs are aggregated to a GCS location.

Comment: Hi @Jerry, You can directly attach [Local SSD’s](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/compute/dataproc-local-ssds) while creating a Dataproc cluster to meet your requirement. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Hi @Jerry, I found the Github issue you had raised. Posting the [issue link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/initialization-actions/issues/1007) here for posterity.